# Return a html img tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a simple project where I'm showing my github profile in vanilla javascript.

```js
let requestURL = 'https://api.github.com/users/fcfidel';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

request.onload = function() {
    var githubInfo = request.response;
    populateHeader(githubInfo);
    //showGithubInfo(githubInfo);
}

function populateHeader(jsonObj) {
    var myH1 = document.createElement('h1');

    //myH1.textContent = jsonObj['login'];
    myH1.textContent = `<img src="${jsonObj['avatar_url']}" />`;
    image.appendChild(myH1);

    var myPara = document.createElement('p');
    myPara.textContent = 'Name: ' + jsonObj['name'] + ' // Formed: ' + jsonObj['created_at'];
   image.appendChild(myPara);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="image"></div>

<div class="name"></div>
<script>
    var image = document.querySelector('.image');
    var name = document.querySelector('.name');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to find a way to return the  in javascript but I just can't find a way :(

The only way I kind of found a way was with the **template literal**
it works but not that way I want, it does return what I want but...

this is the result:
[image]
I know the solution is something really simple, but I just can't even no more...

this is the result that I want:
[image]

Im learning javascript Im still a noob... Im doing the exercises from the MDN :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the image source instead of adding it to the div. Also the backticks are not helping!

Add image tag and modify the ajax call to use:

```
document.querySelector('#my-image').src = jsonObj['avatar_url'];
```

```js
let requestURL = 'https://api.github.com/users/fcfidel';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

request.onload = function() {
  var githubInfo = request.response;
  populateHeader(githubInfo);
  //showGithubInfo(githubInfo);
}

function populateHeader(jsonObj) {
  var myH1 = document.createElement('h1');

  //myH1.textContent = jsonObj['login'];
  //myH1.textContent = `<img src="${jsonObj['avatar_url']}" />`;
  //image.appendChild(myH1);

  var myPara = document.createElement('p');
  myPara.textContent = 'Name: ' + jsonObj['name'] + ' // Formed: ' + jsonObj['created_at'];
  image.appendChild(myPara);
  
  document.querySelector('#my-image').src = jsonObj['avatar_url'];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="image">
  <img id="my-image" src="" />
  </div>

  <div class="name"></div>
  <script>
    var image = document.querySelector('.image');
    var name = document.querySelector('.name');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Good luck with the coding mate!